# Animated Vector Drawable for on click rotation of arrow

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I need to have an [expandable recycler view](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/tree/master/sampleapp/src/main/res/drawable). I am planning to use an animated vector drawable for the collapse and expand arrow animation.

There is this `setExpandCollapseListener` using which I can start the rotation. How to use Animated Vector Drawable to get the same effect as shown below?

Vector drawable for expand button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="306"
android:viewportHeight="306"
android:width="306dp"
android:height="306dp">
<path
    android:pathData="M153 247.35L306 94.35 270.3 58.65 153 175.95 35.7 58.65 0 94.35Z"
    android:fillColor="#000000" />
</vector>
```

Vector drawable for collapse button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="306"
android:viewportHeight="306"
android:width="306dp"
android:height="306dp">
<path
    android:pathData="M270.3 247.35L306 211.65 153 58.65 0 211.65 35.7 247.35 153 130.05Z"
    android:fillColor="#000000" />
</vector>
```

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All you need is just one line of code -

```
view.animate().rotationBy(degree_of_rotation).setDuration(duration_in_milliseconds).start();
```

Comment: but u need view, not **Drawable**.

Answer (score 10):

**1. Add vector images**

We also need to wrap `path` in `group` because `group` is the part of vector resource that will be animated. You can set any name for a group.

`res/drawable/ic_arrow_down.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="306"
    android:viewportHeight="306"
    android:width="306dp"
    android:height="306dp">

    <group
     android:name="arrow"
     android:pivotX="153"
     android:pivotY="153">
        <path
            android:pathData="M153 247.35L306 94.35 270.3 58.65 153 175.95 35.7 58.65 0 94.35Z"
            android:fillColor="#000000" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

`res/drawable/ic_arrow_top.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="306"
    android:viewportHeight="306"
    android:width="306dp"
    android:height="306dp">

    <group
     android:name="arrow"
     android:pivotX="153"
     android:pivotY="153">
         <path
             android:pathData="M270.3 247.35L306 211.65 153 58.65 0 211.65 35.7 247.35 153 130.05Z"
             android:fillColor="#000000" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

**2. Add animator**

`res/animator/animation_arrow_rotation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="180" />
```

**3. Add animated vector drawables**

`<target>` references to the `group`'s name.

`res/drawable/ic_animated_arrow_down.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_down">

    <target
        android:name="arrow"
        android:animation="@animator/animation_arrow_rotation" />
</animated-vector>
```

`res/drawable/ic_animated_arrow_up.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_up">

    <target
        android:name="arrow"
        android:animation="@animator/animation_arrow_rotation" />
</animated-vector>
```

**4. Add some code to Adapter**

Init ImageView in ParentViewHolder's inheritor:

```
void bind(UiModel uiModel) {
    arrowImageView.setImageResource(isExpanded() ? R.drawable.ic_animated_arrow_down :
            R.drawable.ic_animated_arrow_up);

    // some other code 
}
```

and override `onExpansionToggled`:

```
@Override
public void onExpansionToggled(boolean expanded) {
    super.onExpansionToggled(expanded);

    arrowImageView.setImageResource(expanded ? R.drawable.ic_animated_arrow_down :
            R.drawable.ic_animated_arrow_up);
    AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat drawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) arrowImageView.getDrawable();

    drawable.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable ignored) {
            drawable.clearAnimationCallbacks();

            arrowImageView.setImageResource(expanded ? R.drawable.ic_animated_arrow_up :
                    R.drawable.ic_animated_arrow_down);
        }
    });

    drawable.start();
}
```

By the way, you can define AnimatedVectorDrawable XML resources in one XML file. Details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html).